# windows is not booting after installing ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I installed ubuntu 14.04.1 along side windows7. i remember that i gave automatic resizing of parition while installing ubuntu. Now i am unable to boot windows 7. on the boot screen i am having the following..

```
*ubuntu
Memtest
Memtest
windows 7
```

Can you please help me to boot windows 7.

Comment: Select the Windows 7 entry and press enter.....

Answer (score 0):

Use the <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> keys on your keyboard (not with the mouse) to go to Windows 7 and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)